# How to append strings using sprintf?

Tags: c, printf

I am facing a serious issue with `sprintf`.

Suppose my code snippet is:

```
sprintf(Buffer,"Hello World");
sprintf(Buffer,"Good Morning");
sprintf(Buffer,"Good Afternoon");
.
.
.
```

Some hundred sprints....

If I do like this, it's getting overwritten.

How can I avoid overwriting using `sprintf`? If I give a `printf` at the end I want to see all the lines.

Comment: I shall not use sprintf but snprintf,
I shall not use printf( str ) but printf( "%s" , str )

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You need:

```
sprintf(Buffer,"Hello World");
sprintf(Buffer + strlen(Buffer),"Good Morning");
sprintf(Buffer + strlen(Buffer),"Good Afternoon");
```

and of course you need your buffer to be big enough.

Comment: +1 although I like Aeth's solution a bit better, it seems a bit more efficient than recalculating the string length every time.

Comment: A trick I've seen along these lines is to `#define eos(s) ((s)+strlen(s))`, or declare a function if you prefer.  Then you can use `sprintf(eos(Buffer), "Stuff")`

Comment: Simpler still, you can just use `sprintf(strchr(s, '\0'), "...")`.

Comment: What is the + strlen(Buffer) appending to the actual Buffer for?

Comment: This is pointer arithmetic. It's like adding the current length of the string to the start address of the 'Buffer'. This operation is not safe for mbs and unicode strings. Like for instance, getting length of unicode string "Hello" would return 5, but actually *Buffer + 5 * sizeof(wchar_t)* is required in this case

Answer (score 85):

```
int length = 0;
length += sprintf(Buffer+length, "Hello World");
length += sprintf(Buffer+length, "Good Morning");
length += sprintf(Buffer+length, "Good Afternoon");
```

Here is a version with some resistance to errors.  It is useful if you do not care when errors happen so long as you can continue along your merry way when they do.

```
int bytes_added( int result_of_sprintf )
{
    return (result_of_sprintf > 0) ? result_of_sprintf : 0;
}

int length = 0;
length += bytes_added(sprintf(Buffer+length, "Hello World"));
length += bytes_added(sprintf(Buffer+length, "Good Morning"));
length += bytes_added(sprintf(Buffer+length, "Good Afternoon"));
```

Comment: But what happens if sprintf experiences  a conversion failure?

Comment: Then you have bad things that happen.  I omitted the error checking for the sake of brevity.

Comment: +1 - Additional error checking should be an exercise for the reader anyway. After all, its _their_ code :)

Comment: I guess make sense to report error and errono in case of negative result of sprintf.

Answer (score 36):

For safety (buffer overflow) I recommend to use snprintf()

```
const int MAX_BUF = 1000;
char* Buffer = malloc(MAX_BUF);

int length = 0;
length += snprintf(Buffer+length, MAX_BUF-length, "Hello World");
length += snprintf(Buffer+length, MAX_BUF-length, "Good Morning");
length += snprintf(Buffer+length, MAX_BUF-length, "Good Afternoon");
```

Comment: The second argument of snprintf is unsigned (size_t), it means that if length > MAX_BUF, then MAX_BUF-length will underflow and snprintf will happily write outside of the buffer creating a buffer overflow. Note that the return of snprintf is equal to the number of bytes which would have been written if enough space had been available and NOT the number of bytes really written.

Answer (score 17):

A `snprintfcat()` wrapper for `snprintf()`:

```
size_t 
snprintfcat(
    char* buf,
    size_t bufSize,
    char const* fmt,
    ...)
{
    size_t result;
    va_list args;
    size_t len = strnlen( buf, bufSize);

    va_start( args, fmt);
    result = vsnprintf( buf + len, bufSize - len, fmt, args);
    va_end( args);

    return result + len;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Use the return value of `sprintf()`

```
Buffer += sprintf(Buffer,"Hello World");
Buffer += sprintf(Buffer,"Good Morning");
Buffer += sprintf(Buffer,"Good Afternoon");
```

Comment: This is the best solution, no need to strlen

Comment: Note that you also need to save the starting address of the buffer for further reference.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you want to use `sprintf` for string concatenation when there are methods intended specifically for what you need such as [`strcat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/) and [`strncat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncat/)?

Comment: It could be that the example was the trivial case only strings are being appended.  The problem can be extended to include cases where you are appending other types of formatted data for which `strcat` would not apply.

Answer (score 5):

I find the following method works nicely.

```
sprintf(Buffer,"Hello World");
sprintf(&Buffer[strlen(Buffer)],"Good Morning");
sprintf(&Buffer[strlen(Buffer)],"Good Afternoon");
```

Comment: `[...]` around `strlen`? Should it be `(...)`?

Comment: too much python :D

Answer (score 5):

**Small full code example**

Using flat plain **stdio** standard library only

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
    {
    char c[1024];
    int  i=0;

    i+=sprintf(c+i,"We "   );
    i+=sprintf(c+i,"Love " );
       sprintf(c+i,"Coding");

    printf("%s",c);
    }
```

OUTPUT: **We Love Coding**

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for `fmemopen(3)`:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[128] = { 0 };
    FILE *fp = fmemopen(buf, sizeof(buf), "w");

    assert(fp);

    fprintf(fp, "Hello World!\n");
    fprintf(fp, "%s also work, of course.\n", "Format specifiers");
    fclose(fp);

    puts(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

If dynamic storage is more suitable for you use-case you could follow Liam's excellent suggestion about using `open_memstream(3)`:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *buf;
    size_t size;
    FILE *fp = open_memstream(&buf, &size);

    assert(fp);

    fprintf(fp, "Hello World!\n");
    fprintf(fp, "%s also work, of course.\n", "Format specifiers");
    fclose(fp);

    puts(buf);
    free(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. At the suggestion of man fmemopen, I found open_memstream to be a little more suitable for my application. See the [GNU manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Streams.html) for an example.

Comment: @Liam awesome, thanks for the tip about `open_memstream`. I added an example for that as well.

Comment: Fantastic, except neither `fmemopen` nor `open_memstream` are available on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Are you simply appending string literals?  Or are you going to be appending various data types (ints, floats, etc.)?

It might be easier to abstract this out into its own function (the following assumes C99):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>

int appendToStr(char *target, size_t targetSize, const char * restrict format, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  char temp[targetSize];
  int result;

  va_start(args, format);
  result = vsnprintf(temp, targetSize, format, args);
  if (result != EOF)
  {
    if (strlen(temp) + strlen(target) > targetSize)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "appendToStr: target buffer not large enough to hold additional string");
      return 0;
    }
    strcat(target, temp);
  }
  va_end(args);
  return result;
}
```

And you would use it like so:

```
char target[100] = {0};
...
appendToStr(target, sizeof target, "%s %d %f\n", "This is a test", 42, 3.14159);
appendToStr(target, sizeof target, "blah blah blah");
```

etc.

The function returns the value from `vsprintf`, which in most implementations is the number of bytes written to the destination.  There are a few holes in this implementation, but it should give you some ideas.

Comment: Why don't you put sizeof target inside the function? Why do you need it in parameters?

Comment: @hellomyfriends: Because in the function, `target` is a pointer to `char`, not an array of `char`, and `sizeof` will only return the size of the pointer, not the size of the array that it points to.

Answer (score 2):

Use strcat http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/

```
int main ()
    {
      char str[80];
      strcpy (str,"these ");
      strcat (str,"strings ");
      strcat (str,"are ");
      strcat (str,"concatenated.");
      puts (str);
      return 0;
    }




    Output:


    these strings are concatenated.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the simple line shown below to append strings in one buffer:

```
sprintf(Buffer,"%s %s %s","Hello World","Good Morning","Good Afternoon");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char string1[] = "test";
char string2[] = "string";
int len = sizeof(string1) + sizeof(string2);
char totalString[len];
sprintf(totalString, "%s%s",string1,string2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I write a function support dynamic variable string append, like PHP str append: str . str . ... etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int str_append(char **json, const char *format, ...)
{
    char *str = NULL;
    char *old_json = NULL, *new_json = NULL;

    va_list arg_ptr;
    va_start(arg_ptr, format);
    vasprintf(&str, format, arg_ptr);

    // save old json
    asprintf(&old_json, "%s", (*json == NULL ? "" : *json));

    // calloc new json memory
    new_json = (char *)calloc(strlen(old_json) + strlen(str) + 1, sizeof(char));

    strcat(new_json, old_json);
    strcat(new_json, str);

    if (*json) free(*json);
    *json = new_json;

    free(old_json);
    free(str);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *json = NULL;

    /*
    str_append(&json, "name: %d, %d, %d", 1, 2, 3);
    str_append(&json, "sex: %s", "male");
    str_append(&json, "end");
    str_append(&json, "");
    str_append(&json, "{\"ret\":true}");
    */

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        str_append(&json, "id-%d", i);
    }

    printf("%s\n", json);

    if (json) free(json);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Using [strcat](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat)(`buffer`,"`Your new string...here`"), as an option.

Comment: This duplicates a more complete existing answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40316229/874188

Answer (score -4):

What about:

```
char s[100] = "";

sprintf(s, "%s%s", s, "s1");

sprintf(s, "%s%s", s, "s2");

sprintf(s, "%s%s", s, "s3");

printf("%s", s);
```

But take into account possible buffer ovewflows!

Comment: It is probably not a safe move to be using `s` as a source to be read from as well as a destination to be written to.  I would liken it to calling `strcpy(s, s)`.