# Is there method of in place string manipulation native to the mingw libraries that doesn't involve i/o streams

Tags: c++, printf, sstream, manipulators

I am attempting to construct a serial number of a certain format.  This number will be entered into a database.  At this point I am having to use sprintf, but I would like a native C++ method for it.

Here is sample code:

```
int i;

sprintf(buffer, "%03d", i);
```

The integer will be anywhere from 1 to 3 digits.  The format needs to look like this:

001, ... 013, ... 101, ... etc.

The "serial number" has the format:

AAAAA001, ... AAAAA013, ... AAAAA101, etc.

So the question is, is there a way to do this that is native to C++ without having to use iostream manipulators and that is included in the mingw-w64 libraries.  Or does it require something like boost libraries?

Another way to put it: is there a drop-in replacement in C++ for the C sprintf function?

Edit based upon comments:

So there is nothing as simple as....

```
int i;
string buffer;

sprintf(buffer, "%03d", i);
```

I realize that this does not work, but it gives the thought anyway.  There is no way to operate directly on a string class object with a method that serves the function of sprintf?

Comment: There's [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) but that doesn't allow for specifying format. Even `boost::format` uses string streams under the hood.

Comment: So it won't "taint the purity" of the c++ code to use sprintf in the end?

Comment: [`std::sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) is part of the C++ standard as much as IO streams are and has the advantage of being significantly faster than any formatting library using streams. However since it originates from C it is especially difficult to use safely and you may want to look at `std::snprintf` instead.

Comment: When you say "safely" do you mean that it has platform dependent characteristics?

Comment: I mean that is is neither type safe nor memory safe, [using it without utmost care can result in bugs or outright security vulnerabilities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662899/understanding-the-dangers-of-sprintf)

Comment: Okay.  I looked at your link and can understand that.  I've edited the original question to make it more precise.

Comment: I think the real question you have to answer first is "why do you not want to use `sstream` "? Without establishing that first, it's a bit of an XYProblem, since `sstream` will certainly solve the given problem clearly, type-safely and relatively efficiently.

Comment: Since you know ahead of time exactly how many characters your formatted string will have, `std::snprintf` with a fixed-size buffer ought to be a fast, safe and convenient solution.  You can easily create a `std::string` from the `char[]` buffer later if you need to.

Comment: I hadn't come across sstream when I was looking around.  Since it seems to have associated formatting functions, it may do the trick.  I guess that my understanding of streams was too narrow.  Thanks.  aruisdante  If you will enter your suggestion as the answer to the question.  I will accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking aruisdante's answer as the best answer to the question although it is a stream which I initially found undesirable.

> I think the real question you have to answer first is "why do you not want >to use sstream "? Without establishing that first, it's a bit of an >XYProblem, since sstream will certainly solve the given problem clearly, >type-safely and relatively efficiently. –  aruisdante

My understanding of streams was too narrow.  It looks like a stringstream should work well for my application.

Thanks again.