# invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator+'

Tags: c++, gps, lora

Using an Adafruit Feather M0 board with LoRa radio, I want to send GPS position to a receiver. When trying to create a data packet with an ISO 8601 timestamp and lat/long GPS values I am using the following code to create a `char` array and then send it:

```
char radiopacket[40] = {GPS.year + "-" + GPS.month + "-" + GPS.day + "T" + GPS.hour + ":" + GPS.minute + ":" + GPS.seconds + "Z" + "," + GPS.latitude + "," + GPS.longitude};
rf95.send((uint8_t *)radiopacket, 40);
```

I keep getting the error:

> invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [2]' to binary
>   'operator+'

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't concatenate strings like that in C. Try something like

```
char radiopacket[40];
sprintf(radiopacket, "%04d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02dZ,%f,%f", GPS.year, GPS.month, GPS.day, GPS.hour, GPS.minute, GPS.seconds, GPS.latitude, GPS.longitude); 
rf95.send((uint8_t *)radiopacket, 40);
```

see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) for some documentation on the format string (the `"%04d-..."`) within `sprintf`

Comment: `sprintf` is not secure, please use `snprintf` instead, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3662918/2666212)

Comment: Thanks! That has worked

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess and say you're coming from python.

I think what you need is 
[std::stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)