# How to simply convert a float to a string in c?

Tags: c

```
FILE * fPointer;
float amount = 3.1415;
fPointer =fopen("vending.txt","w");
fprintf(fPointer, amount);
printf("The file has been created for the first time and we added the value %f", amount);
fclose(fPointer);
```

I am trying to save a float number to a text file but when I try to run this code it triggers a compiling errors because the function `fprintf` expects the second parameter to be an array of characters so how can I convert my float to a string so I can pass it, I have a **C#** background where something like `.toString()` is possible so is there any thing like that in **C** to directly cast a float to a string?

Comment: Why the tag c# and c++ ?

Comment: why have you tagged c# and c++ if you're using c??

Comment: it was a mistake but somebody already deleted them for me , thanks .

Comment: No this question is in c while the link you have pasted is a solution to a problem to c++

Comment: Voting to re-open as post was mis-tagged, tags corrected, yet dupe refers to another language's answer that is irrelevant to his question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you can use C99 standard, then the best way is to use `snprintf` function. On first call you can pass it a zero-length (null) buffer and it will then return the length required to convert the floating-point value into a string. Then allocate the required memory according to what it returned and then convert safely.

This addresses the problem with sprintf that were discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662899/understanding-the-dangers-of-sprintf).

Example:

```
int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%f", amount);
char *result = malloc(len + 1);
snprintf(result, len + 1, "%f", amount);
// do stuff with result
free(result);
```

Answer (score 8):

The second parameter is the format string after which the format arguments follow:

```
fprintf(fPointer, "%f", amount);
```

`%f` tells `fprintf` to write this argument (`amount`) as string representation of the float value.

A list of possible format specifiers can (for example) be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/).

Comment: Suggest `"%e"` instead of `"%f"`.  The latter will print nearly half of all `float` as `"0.000000'` or `"-0.000000'`.

Answer (score 3):

By using ***`sprintf()`*** we can convert from float to string in c language
for better understanding see the below code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   float f = 1.123456789;
   char c[50]; //size of the number
   sprintf(c, "%g", f);
   printf(c);
   printf("\n");
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
// OP's code           v---- Format string expected here. 
// fprintf(fPointer, amount);
```

---

To print different text for each `float`, use the format string `"%.*e"`.
`FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1` is the number of digits needed to print each `float` value uniquely without undue precision.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>

fprintf(fPointer, "%.*e", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, amount);
```

---

Using `"%f"` will print nearly half of small `float` like `0.000000001f` and `-1.2345e-10` as `0.000000` or `-0.000000`.

Using `"%f"` will print large `float` like `FLT_MAX` with verbose text  like "340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000".