# Not able to read all data from buffer in kernel read function

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Here is my code for read function in proc kernel module

```
int read_proc(struct file *filp,char *buf,size_t count,loff_t *offset ) 
{
    struct task_struct *task = current;         
    ssize_t bytes = count < (MAX_MSG_LEN-(*offset)) ? count : (MAX_MSG_LEN-(*offset));

    do
    {
        task = task->parent;
        sprintf(buf, "assignment: parent process: %s, PID: %d Utime: %d , stime: %ld \n ", task->comm, task->pid,task->utime,task->stime) ;  
    } while (task->pid != 0);

    (*offset) += bytes;
    return bytes;
}
```

In this code I'm only able to read the last **zero number PID process** from the buffer but I want to read all the running processes and its PID

I have modified the code from this link:
https://jlmedina123.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/current-variable-and-task_struct/

My output:

```
assignment: parent process: swapper/0, PID: 0 Utime: 0 , stime: 1201744387 

668726 
assignment: parent process: swapper/0, PID: 0 Utime: 0 , stime: 1201761343 

195869 
assignment: parent process: swapper/0, PID: 0 Utime: 0 , stime: 1201791953
```

**I want to read all the process id and running process which i have copied into the   buffer !!! please tell me where I have done wrong?**

Comment: Is it a *Linux* kernel module? Please edit your question to include proper tags.

Comment: To read the buffer from my module I use   "cat  /proc/module_name"    command.

Comment: ``do { ... } while (...)`` is sometimes frowned upon. The code is executed at least once and what if the magical (global variable?) ``current`` has no parent in the first place?

Comment: Yes!!!  It is Linux  Kernel module

Comment: Actually `current`   I have used to read the current running process. But I have not used yet in my code.

Comment: Seems to me that you keep overwriting `buf` in the loop, i.e. `buf` will only contain data from the last loop (which has pid equal zero)

Comment: Perhaps this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674312/how-to-append-strings-using-sprintf

Comment: Thank you !!!!! so much ......my problem is get resolved ...The problem is with the buffer overwriting .....and it gets resolved by `strlen(buf)` function

Comment: It's easier if you use `single_open` and the `seq_file` interface. See "fs/proc/version.c" in the Linux kernel sources for a very simple example.