# Send file using POST [ Unable to upload ] in C++

Tags: php, c++, http, winapi, post

I am having trouble in  Sending File to my Server. I have checked some other questions tried to resolve most of the issues but at the end i am not able to upload the file
Here is my C++ code :

```
   #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#pragma comment(lib,"wininet.lib")
#define ERROR_OPEN_FILE       10
#define ERROR_MEMORY          11
#define ERROR_SIZE            12
#define ERROR_INTERNET_OPEN   13
#define ERROR_INTERNET_CONN   14
#define ERROR_INTERNET_REQ    15
#define ERROR_INTERNET_SEND   16

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Local variables
    static char *filename = "perf.txt";   //Filename to be loaded
    static char *filepath = "C:\\perf.txt";   //Filename to be loaded
    static char *type = "text/plain";
    static char boundary[] = "BOUNDARY";            //Header boundary
    static char nameForm[] = "file";     //Input form name
    static char iaddr[] = "2e8cd930.ngrok.io";        //IP address
    static char url[] = "/post/upload.php";         //URL

    char hdrs[512] = { '-' };                  //Headers
    char * buffer;                   //Buffer containing file + headers
    char * content;                  //Buffer containing file
    FILE * pFile;                    //File pointer
    long lSize;                      //File size
    size_t result;

    // Open file
    pFile = fopen(filepath, "rb");
    if (pFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR_OPEN_FILE");
        getchar();
        return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;
    }
    printf("OPEN_FILE\n");

    // obtain file size:
    fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell(pFile);
    rewind(pFile);

    // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
    content = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(lSize + 1));
    if (content == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR_MEMORY");
        getchar();
        return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;
    }
    printf("MEMORY_ALLOCATED\t \"%d\" \n", &lSize);
    // copy the file into the buffer:
    result = fread(content, 1, lSize, pFile);
    if (result != lSize)
    {
        printf("ERROR_SIZE");
        getchar();
        return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;
    }
    printf("SIZE_OK\n");

    content[lSize] = '\0';

    // terminate
    fclose(pFile);
    printf("FILE_CLOSE\n");
    //allocate memory to contain the whole file + HEADER
    buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize + 2048);

    //print header
    sprintf(hdrs, "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=%s", boundary);
    sprintf(buffer, "-%s\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%s\"; filename=\"%s\"\r\n", boundary, nameForm, filename);
    sprintf(buffer, "%sContent-Type: %s\r\n", buffer, type);
    sprintf(buffer, "%s\r\n\r\n%s", buffer, content);
    sprintf(buffer, "%s\r\n-%s-\r\n", buffer, boundary);

    printf("%s", buffer);

    //Open internet connection
    HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen("WINDOWS", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (hSession == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR_INTERNET_OPEN");
        getchar();
        return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;
    }
    printf("INTERNET_OPENED\n");

    HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, iaddr, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    if (hConnect == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR_INTERNET_CONN");
        getchar();
        return ERROR_INTERNET_CONN;
    }
    printf("INTERNET_CONNECTED\n");

    HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, (const char*)"POST", _T(url), NULL, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 1);
    if (hRequest == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR_INTERNET_REQ");
        getchar();

    }
    printf("INTERNET_REQ_OPEN\n");

    BOOL sent = HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), buffer, strlen(buffer));

    if (!sent)
    {
        printf("ERROR_INTERNET_SEND");
        getchar();
        return ERROR_INTERNET_CONN;
    }
    printf("INTERNET_SEND_OK\n");

    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
    InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my PHP code [ upload.php] , i have already changed upload folder Permissions for others to create and Delete files:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = 'upload/';

if (is_uploaded_file(isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])?($_FILES['file'['tmp_name']]):0)) 
{
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    echo "File ". $_FILES['file']['name'] ." uploaded successfully. ";

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
    {
        echo "File was moved! ";
    }
    else
    {
        print_r($_FILES);
    }
}
else 
{
    print_r($_FILES);
}
?>
```

Using Wireshark my Post Request and Response is [ I have already Tried Replacing two new lines with 1 line after Content -Type line but not helped
After Changing Delimiter    :

```
    POST /post/upload.php HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY
User-Agent: WINDOWS
Host: 2e8cd930.ngrok.io
Content-Length: 130
Cache-Control: no-cache

-BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="perf.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain


Whats Up?
-BOUNDARY-
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 25 Nov 2017 11:25:16 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.27 (Debian)
Content-Length: 10
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Array
(
)
```

I don't know why my Server reply coming out with Array (). The file is not being uploaded.

Comment: At least your closing delimiter is wrong as well as the delimiter in the header. — isn’t part of the boundary so remove it from headers. Closing delimiter also needs — in the end. Your sprintfs are also bad since they copy the existing data over and over instead of appending new data. And you’re missing \r before body.

Comment: Sorry, i cant understand what you mean. Can you please elaborate or edit in code so i can understand

Answer (score 0):

The first problems I can see:

You say in your headers that the delimiter is `—BOUNDARY` and then use the same string as the actual delimiter. This is wrong. The format is

```
—DELIMITER
content
—DELIMITER
content
—DELIMITER—
```

So your headers should say just `BOUNDARY` as the delimiter.

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY
```

You also need to add the trailing `—` to the closing delimiter.

You also have `\r\n\n` when separating headers from the body. It should be `\r\n\r\n`.

These errors will cause the MIME parser not to find any form data anywhere.

Performance-wise you shouldn’t use `sprintf` to append data by putting the buffer as first and then what you want to append. It’ll cause way too much copying data which is already there. You should use `strncat` rather since everything is strings to be appended. Or monitoring the string length and using `sprintf` to the end to append. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674312/how-to-append-strings-using-sprintf) for more information.

Comment: I have Changed Delimiter and my updated request is above but i am still not able to  upload the file ?? Any suggestion