# system(); not allowing me to pass in variables

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to make something that compiles and runs .c files in one command. But I'm having a problem. I got the filename  through the get_string(); under the_ cs50.h_ library.

And now I'm to give the `system()` function this command `make {filename}` by doing this

```
system("make %s", filename")
```

But it just gives this error back:

```
mac.c:18:23: error: too many arguments to function call, expected single argument '__command', have 2 arguments
    system("make %s", filename);
    ~~~~~~            ^~~~~~~~
```

I understand that It means that the `system()` function has too many arguments but I don't know any other way to add in the filename after make.

Here is a copy of the code I am using if you need to look at it more. Thanks! [Click Here to go to the github page](https://github.com/OkiStuff/mac/blob/master/mac.c) If you find a fix, either comment it or you can do a pull request at the github!

Comment: Not every function that takes a string works like `printf`.

Comment: I realized that, that's why I need a alternative way to combine them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That compilation error is raised because [`system()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system) expects only one string argument.

If you need to make the command dependent to a parameter, first build it with `sprintf`:

```
char command[256];

sprintf(command, "make %250s", filename);
system (command);
```

The `%250s` format is to avoid that, in the unlikely case that `filename` is longer than 250 characters, we go *out of bounds* of `command` array.

A safer function allowing to limit the total length is [snprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf):

```
snprintf(command, 255, "make %s", filename);
```

Comment: If `filename` is over 250 characters, this will end badly.

Comment: It works! Just little notice. instead of `sprinf( command, "{command}", filename" )` just do `sprinf( command, "{command}", filename )`

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica you know, I was writing my `snprintf` solution or the `%250s` one. But since I didn't want to explain that part I thought that the simple sprintf was enough. Well: SOguys doesn't forgive! I'll edit it.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica PS: on Windows MAX_PATH is 260...

Comment: @TECHSCHOOL200000 you are right. I'm sorry fo the rejected edit. The system rejected it because I was editing the answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

`system()` only takes a single parameter. You need to build up the string beforehand, and then pass it already built.

For that, you probably are looking for a function like `sprintf()`.

Comment: By any chance could I have an example on how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: @TECHSCHOOL200000 The best you can do is search for questions about `sprintf` like [this one perhaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674312/how-to-append-strings-using-sprintf).